# Leaving div fixed even with dynamic parent

Tags: html, css

How do I create two divs that occupy 100% of the screen and stand next to each other? where when the view is dimmed the first view is not redirected.

```
 ___________________________
|     |                     |
| nav |  container          |
|     |                     |
|     |                     |
|_____|_______footer________|
```

after reducing the screen

```
  ____________________
 |     |              |
 | nav |  container   |
 |     |              |
 |_____|____footer____|
```

the container decreases the width but the nav does not

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
  <title>Sibcom - Layout</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
  
 <body>
  <div>
   <div>
    <nav class="menuVertical" style="float:left; background:pink; min-height: calc(100vh - 75px); width:20%; "> 
     Menu Vertical
    </nav>
    
    <!-- Conteudo -->
    <div class="conteudo" style="float:left; background:green; width:80%;"> 
     <!-- Cabeçalho de navegação -->
     <div style="background:blue;height:60px;margin-bottom:20px;">
      Área de navegação
     </div>
     
     <!-- Conteudo -->
     <div style="background:yellow;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;">
      Conteudo <br>
      Conteudo <br>   
     </div>
     
     <footer style="background:gray;">
      Footer
     </footer>
    
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Wrap the container and navigation in a parent with `display: flex` to force the children to align side-by-side.

Because you don't want the navigation to change size, you can give it a set width, like `width: 150px;`

Finally, because you'd like the container to change size to occupy the remaining space, you can apply `flex-grow: 1;`.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <nav>NAV</nav>
  <div class="container">
    CONTAINER
    <div class="footer">
      FOOTER
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this was what I needed, just one more question is the correct semantics <div class = "nav"> or <nav>?

Comment: @BrunoSilva Either works, but `<nav>` may be more friendly in this case. Keep in mind, you'll need to update the CSS to be `nav` instead of `.nav`. I've edited my answer to account for this.

Answer (score -1):

Use Flexbox! the outside container holds 2 items, the main container and the footer, and has direction set to column so one is on top of the other. The the inside container is set by default to row, and also has 2 items, the left menu and the content item.

The outside container has min height set to 100vh (visor height), meaning it will always be 100% of the screen, and the container class sets its own height to 90% of this previous container, leaving 10% for the footer. You can play around with these numbers to adjust as you want.

```css
.outside-container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     min-height: 100vh;
 }

.container {
     display: flex;
     min-height: 90%;
 }

.menuVertical {
    float:left;
    background:pink;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 75px); 
    width:20%;
    }
    
.conteudo {
    float:left;
    background:green;
    width:80%;
    }
    
.header {
    background:blue;
    height:60px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    }

.content {
    background:yellow;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

footer {
    background:gray
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
  <title>Sibcom - Layout</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
  
 <body>
  <div class='outside-container'>
  <div class='container'>
    <nav class="menuVertical"> 
     Menu Vertical
    </nav>
    
    <!-- Conteudo -->
    <div class="conteudo"> 
     <!-- Cabeçalho de navegação -->
     <div class="header">
      Área de navegação
     </div>
     
     <!-- Conteudo -->
     <div class="content">
      Conteudo <br>
      Conteudo <br>   
     </div>

      </div>
      

    </div>
    
      <footer>
        Footer
      </footer>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A note: `flex` is a *replacement* for `float`. You'd use one or the other, not both. However, `flex` is the more modern approach.

Comment: @Santi thanks, didn't know that. I just copied his style into a separate stylesheet, didn't notice the innards beyond what I needed to style it.